# Polymer 1.0 adding attributes to child doms in a repeat

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have this structure, and I want to bind , say custom attributes or non-standard attributes like ***for*** or ***some-new-attribute*** to child doms created by a dom-repeat template. How do i achieve this?

```
<dom-module id="card-list">

<template>
    <li>Some Text</li>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{items}}" >
        <li id="{{ item.text }}" for="{{ item.text }}">{{ item.text }}</li>
    </template> 
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: "card-list",
    extends:"ul",
    ready: function() {
      this.items = magically_get_an_array_of_objects();
    },
});
</script>

</dom-module>
```

If magically_get_an_array_of_texts function returns this array of objects

```
[
 {text:"foo"},
 {text:"bar"}
]
```

The resulting template would be this

```
<ul is="card-list">
    <li>Some Text</li>
    <li id="foo">foo</li>
    <li id="bar">bar</li>
</ul>
```

Notice how the ***for*** attribute did not get binded.

**Question**
How do you bind to attributes to child doms, specifically when they are looped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use [binding to native element attribute](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#native-binding).

```
for$="{{ item.text }}"
```

[image: Binding to native element attribute]

Comment: I wasn't aware of this solutions. It is simpler than mine and it works.

Comment: Wooah, i didn't see that when i was goinv ovee the docs, good find. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your version will set a property. It will not show up in the HTML, as you noticed, but it will be available as property. `document.querySelector("#foo").for` will print `foo`.
If you want to use custom attributes, you will need to extend the `<li>` element, define the `for` attribute and set `reflectToAttribute` to `true`.

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "card-li",
        extends:"li",
        properties: {
            for: {
                type: String,
                reflectToAttribute: true
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

And then use it like this.

```
<li is="card-li" id="{{ item.text }}" for="{{ item.text }}">{{ item.text }}</li>
```

Comment: ah that makes a lot of sense, thanks that clarified a lot of things.